# No response from HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web

I have MVC project with service like below:

```
namespace comp.Services
{
    public class CompService
    {
        public HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        public CompService()
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("someapiurl");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }

        protected async Task<string> GetProductAsync(string path)
        {
            var resp = "nothing here";
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            return resp;
        }

        public string GetProduct(string path)
        {
            return GetProductAsync(path).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
}
```

and actionResult to view:

```
namespace comp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public CompService compService;
        public HomeController()
        {
            compService = new CompService();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            var timeServer = compService.GetProduct("/api/time");
            ViewBag.timeServer = timeServer;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

When in debuger I encounter this line:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
```

program exit from debuger and there is no respone in browser.

The same code written in console application works.

In VS output is message that response is succes:

```
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.RemoteDependency","time":"2018-02-18T13:48:31","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"rddf:2.2.0-738","ai.internal.nodeName":"DESKTOP-xxxxx","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"DESKTOP-xxxxx"},"data":{"baseType":"RemoteDependencyData","baseData":{"ver":2,"name":"/api/v1/time","id":"xxxxx=","data":"https://api.xxx.com/api/v1/time","duration":"00:00:01.3150000","resultCode":"200","success":true,"type":"Http","target":"xxx","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true"}}}}
```

In browser console output:

```
[14:51:33 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to send message to browser link server:
Error: SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: You should really keep the code async all the way through in stead of trying to mix synchronous and asynchronous code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really keep the code async all the way through in stead of trying to mix synchronous and asynchronous code

```
namespace comp.Services {
    public class CompService {
        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        static CompService() {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("someapiurl");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }

        public async Task<string> GetProductAsync(string path) {
            var resp = string.Empty;
            using(var response = await client.GetAsync(path)) {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                    resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
            return resp;
        }
    }
}
```

The controller action should also be made async

```
namespace comp.Controllers {
    public class HomeController : Controller {
        private CompService compService;

        public HomeController() {
            compService = new CompService();
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> About() {
            var timeServer = await compService.GetProductAsync("api/time");
            ViewBag.timeServer = timeServer;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

That said, the service should also be abstracted

```
public interface ICompService {
    Task<string> GetProductAsync(string path)
}

public class CompService : ICompService {
    //...code removed for brevity
}
```

and injected into the controller instead of creating it manually.

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    private ICompService compService;

    public HomeController(ICompService compService) {
        this.compService = compService;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> About() {
        var timeServer = await compService.GetProductAsync("api/time");
        ViewBag.timeServer = timeServer;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

What you've got is a deadlock. Unlike console apps, ASP.Net applications run in a Synchronization Context. That context is captured when you block with `GetResult()`. Then, in `GetProductAsync`, you await on the context that is blocked. It cannot resume until `GetResult` is done which cannot resolve until the await is done.

@NKosi 's answer should resolve the problem, there is no reason for you to have any synchronous code.

### For demonstration only

You can *hack* your code to work by explicitly allowing your await to run on a different context. You should not do this in production, it is not a fix. It can fail if someone maintaining the `CompService` is not careful.

To await against a different context change this:

```
 var timeServer = await compService.GetProductAsync("api/time");
```

To this:

```
 var timeServer = await compService.GetProductAsync("api/time").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I mention this only to help you understand what is happening in your code. Don't "fix" it this way and move on.

Comment: Good job mentioning the deadlock. I forgot to mention it in my answer. I'll include a link to reference material in my answer that should cover that.